# Facebook : Tagging user while posting comments to a post via API not working

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I have an app which comments & replies as a Page to the posts.

When i try to post comment with tagging a user on it, this posts the comment without user tagging

**Sent to FB as :**

Post request sent with active page token

```
post_id/comments

Sample message @[120232323232323:Bob Jon]
```

But the message is rendered as

```
Sample message Bob Jon
```

There is no link to the User profile.

later, when the User (Bob) posts a comment in FB for the same post,

My tagging works and i can see a link to the user.

Is there any restriction ?

Comment: I think this answers your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775661/tagging-mentioning-pages-or-users-in-posts-via-graph-api