# Tagging/Mentioning Pages or Users in Posts via Graph Api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Does anybody know a legal and working way to tag / mention other Pages or Users in a Post sent via Graph Api?

I hear it worked some time ago with [ID:USER], but this is not working anymore.

Anybody knows how to do this?

Answer (score 8):

You can't tag people on a **feed** using the Graph API, you have to use Open Graph concepts- [Mention Tagging/ Action Tagging](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/08/21/bringing-mention-tagging-to-open-graph/) (based on your requirement)

There's a small [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14024103/1343690) (not preferred), you can look if it fits your requirement.

But if you want to post a **photo**, then you can tag the people using `tag` parameter.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But Open Graph Concepts are not the solution here since i am not creating actions or objects. My users can post on their page`s feed and they want to use the mentioning features as you can when you post via Facebook Status Box (..by typing @ and selecting). For some reason this was turned of by Facebook. It worked a few motnhs ago.

Comment: Yes. now the only option for you is the open graph

Comment: And as this is no option, i have no option currently you say? ;)

Comment: But why cant you use the OG and create actions/objects? Else you have no option, yes

Comment: Because my User post normal status messages via my app. They don`t do anything realted to an object or action. They can just post to their page. And they want to tag places, pages, people with @ like they are used to from Facebook. ;) You know what i mean?