# How do i mention user in my Comment while replying from FACEBOOK GRAPH API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api-v2.0, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

I am using **Facebook graph API**, I want to know that how can I mention person in a comment while i am replying to the POST?
when i am trying to do it with the format `@[ID:NAME]` E.g `(@[12345:Abc])` it gives me an error like

```
{
"error": {
"message": "(#1705) There was an error posting to this wall",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 1705
}
}
```

Comment: That is simply not possible – users can not be tagged in comments made via API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this post of stack overflow [Tagging/Mentioning Pages or Users in Posts via Graph Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775661/tagging-mentioning-pages-or-users-in-posts-via-graph-api)

I come to know that you cannot tag user via API.

> You can't tag people on a feed using the Graph API, you have to use
>   Open Graph concepts- Mention Tagging/ Action Tagging (based on your
>   requirement)
>
> Source : [Tagging/Mentioning Pages or Users in Posts via Graph Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775661/tagging-mentioning-pages-or-users-in-posts-via-graph-api)

You can use Open Graph API - 
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/08/21/bringing-mention-tagging-to-open-graph/

Comment: Thanks for your help, yeah i got the same answer from CBroe and from other community too.