# How can a site post public messages (timeline/wall posts) on other Pages it does not own via the Facebook API?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-page, facebook-wall

I'm looking to create a site where whenever an event is triggered (e.g. user submits something), it automatically posts publicly on the wall of a Facebook page that it does **not** own (e.g. a company's FB page to alert their Community Managers).

I see [a lot of solutions](https://www.facebook.com/notes/terabug/publish-your-site-content-to-facebook-wall-publish-wall-post-stream-js-api-tutor/458853348988) for posting via the FB API on a wall you own, but I can't find a solution that explains how to post a public message on a Page you do **not** own.

Is this even possible?  If so, then how can this be done?  If not, then how else can you alert other FB Pages (e.g. companies) of posts directed at them to call their attention?

Comment: autoposting is never allowed, and i don´t think it is even possible. what you want to achieve does sound spammy, btw.

Comment: @luschn:  It's no spammier than using the Twitter API to send Tweets @ someone/company when an event is triggered to call the relevant event to their attention as it applies to them.  Twitter allows it so I figured FB did as well.  When you say "autoposting is never allowed", do you mean it is not possible to use the Facebook API to write posts on any public walls?

Comment: if you post something on an event on a page you don´t own, then that´s spam by definition imho. i am pretty sure it´s not possible anyway.

Comment: i just tested it in the api explorer, it´s not possible as i thought.

Answer (score 0):

You can only post to a Page you own, with a Page Token and the `publish_pages` permission. You can´t post on a Page you don´t own. It would be spam anyway imho. If that would be possible, it would be possible for spammers to pretty much spam every single Page they could find.

Comment: OK, so it's not possible to post on someone else's page, but you can post on your own page.  So is there a way to direct a public message on your page to another page, like tagging it with their page username or something along those lines so that they are made aware that the new post is relevant to them?

Comment: no, that would be spammy too. you can only do that manually afaik.

Comment: btw, if you want other pages or users to know about updates, let them like your page. that´s the proper way. forcing them to get notified is spam.

Comment: You keep mentioning spam, but it's only spam if it's done in bulk.  Notifying a company that a post was written about them is not spam as long as it's not done in high volume.  This is why rate-limiting and blocking exists and why Twitter allows their API to mention other users.  Surely Twitter doesn't condone spamming.  You mentioned "AFAIK", so it doesn't seem like you know with 100% certainty if it's possible to mention/notify another page that they've been mentioned in a new post.  I need to confirm if that's indeed possible or not.

Comment: it´s not only spam if you send something in bulk. spam is a notification or information you did not agree to get. that "afaik" was only meant for the manual part, which is possible, i believe.

Comment: anyway, your question was about posting something on the wall of another page with the api. that´s not possible. tagging is a completely different topic, there are some stackoverflow threads about that already afaik. for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775661/tagging-mentioning-pages-or-users-in-posts-via-graph-api